# docker: can not start xvfb-run with docker run, but can start with docker exec -it

Tags: docker, xvfb

I'm trying to run a node app with `xvfb-run`, here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache upgrade && apk add --no-cache chromium coreutils xvfb xvfb-run

ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser"\
  PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true" \
  UPLOAD_ENV="test"

WORKDIR /app

COPY  package.json .
COPY  .npmrc .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

# EXPOSE 9999

ENTRYPOINT xvfb-run -a npm run dev
```

I can successfully build the image, but when I run it with `docker run`, it gets stuck without any log

[image]

But when I open an interactive shell and run the ENTRYPOINT command, it works...

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: The correct written  docke rentrypoint is : **ENTRYPOINT ["xvfb-run", "-a", "npm", "run", "dev"]**, or you can use own entrypoint.sh as bash script and your entrypoint will be **ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh entrypoint.sh"]**

Answer (score 2):

You should add `--init` to `docker run`, for example:

`docker run --init --rm -it $IMAGE$ xvfb-run $COMMAND$`